# Will thorughtput be affected when mixing 802.11n and 802.11ac clients on a single access point?

Tags: wireless-networking, 802.11n, 802.11ac

I have a single AP provided by my ISP vendor which can do both N and AC modes, when I connect with AC client, the benchmarks are pretty fast when communicating with just the AP. But I have two clients, the older client is only capable of N only and both work just fine when they are on their own.

Just recently I'm transferring a lot of files between the newer and older client and I'm wondering if it will make the throughput/latency more efficient when I would force the newer client to use just N mode. The transfer speeds warry between 300kB/s - 1.6MB/s, I wouldn't mind a 1MB/s if it would be stable and consistent. The older client has 8GB RAM, SSD and all the time the CPU load is under 10%, and the newer client 32GB RAM, SSD and CPU load under 10%. So I think the clients are capable of better performance.

Normally I would just do a benchmark, but the Client<->AP<->Client results are inconclusive compared to Client<->AP results. I'm using FileZilla FTP to share the files and the results are very inconsistent, which might be expected from WiFI (making benchmarks random). So it looks like forcing the N doesn't give obvious improvements. However I would like to choose the lesser evil before I will get a chance to redo the network and connecting both with Ethernet (and moving clients, or AP is not possible at moment).

I remember when I had Mikrotik router when I disabled auto-detection of speeds and forced a slower speed it actually made it more stable and faster overall and I wonder if now it's something similar. If forcing the N would stop switching between modes and just keep operating in one mode more efficiently. I disabled roaming agresivesness, power savings and other settings which made sense to me. Still N is fast enough for me (faster than my internet), so I couldn't have noticeable sacrifice by giving up AC, but I wonder if I'm making it worse by forcing the AC client to N.

I have seen similar mixing questions: [Is it okay to mix 802.11n and 802.11ac access points?](https://superuser.com/questions/1392053) and [Can 802.11n and 802.11ac devices share the same router?](https://superuser.com/questions/1535257) but they are not answering my question so I'm asking here.